# EFCore Collection ChangeTracking

Tags: c#, entity-framework-core

I'm using EFCore 2.0 to fetch an object from a SQL database.  This object contains a collection of other objects.

I'm fetching the object like this:

```
var myRequestHistory =_dbContext.EmployeeRequestHistories.Include(x => x.Requests).FirstAsync(x => x.EmployeeId == employeeId);
```

I'm later adding an item to the requests collection:

```
myRequestHistory.Requests.Add(new Request());
```

I need to get a list of the items that changed from the dbContext, but myRequestHistory isn't showing a change, even though I added an object to its collection.

```
    var changedEntities = _dbContext.ChangeTracker.Entries<EmployeeRequestHistory>()
        .Where(x => x.State == EntityState.Added || x.State == EntityState.Deleted || x.State == EntityState.Modified).Select(x => x.Entity).ToList();
```

Why doesn't my updated object appear in the change tracker and how do I get around this?

Answer (score 0):

You didn't added, updated or removed any of `EmployeeRequestHistories`.
What you did — you added a new record to Requests table. After that, no records of EmployeeRequestHistories table were modified.

> var changedEntities = _dbContext.ChangeTracker.Entries

You are filtering by EmployeeRequestHistory — that the reason. Simply filter by Request